# How to insert dashed line in power point using python

Tags: python, python-pptx

i am currently stuck to insert dashed line in power point. there are module using MSO_LINE but not sure how to implement it.

Tq

Answer (score 1):

From [MSO_LINE_DASH_STYLE](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/MsoLineDashStyle.html?highlight=MSO_LINE):

```
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_LINE

shape.line.dash_style = MSO_LINE.DASH_DOT_DOT
```

(I didn't need a dashed line so I haven't done the above; I have solid lines if anything.)

Of course, you might not know how to draw a line. Try something like this:

```
def createLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, shapes):
    # Create line
    line = shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.LINE_INVERSE, x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0)

    # Set shape's outline attributes
    line.line.color.rgb = RGBColor(191, 191, 191)
    line.line.width = Pt(4.0)
```

Obviously you'll need to modify the above and perhaps combine the two fragments but hopefully this is enough to get you going.